# Accessing the 'Media' directory of a Blackberry within the JDK

Tags: blackberry, java-me, filesystems, rim-4.6, jsr75

Trying to use [JSR 75](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75) to access media saved under the '/home/video/' directory on the device.  Using Blackbery JDK 4.6.1.  Single line of code throws a '`FileSystem IO Error`' Exception.  Which is, as usual, unhelpful in the extreme.

```
fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///home/user/videos/"+name, Connector.READ);
```

Has anyone tried to do this?  I can open files within my jar, but can't seem to access the media folder.  I have the `javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.read` permission set and my appplication is signed.

Comment: One suggestion I have is to use:
 - System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.videos");
   Or
 - System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.videos.name");
to get the path to the directory you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two kind of filesystems on BlackBerry - SDCard and store. You have to use one of them, defining it in the path. Standard directory on SDCard where video, music etc stored is "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry".

```
    String standardPath = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry";
    String videoDir = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.videos.name");
    String fileName = "video.txt";
    String path = standardPath+"/"+videoDir+"/"+fileName;
    String content = "";
    FileConnection fconn =  null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    ByteVector bytes = new ByteVector();
    try {
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path, Connector.READ);
        is = fconn.openDataInputStream();

        int c = is.read();
        while(-1 != c)
        {
            bytes.addElement((byte) (c));
            c = is.read();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    content = new String(bytes.toArray());
    add(new RichTextField(content));
```

See also
[SUN Dev Network - Getting Started with the FileConnection APIs](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/index.html)
[RIM Forum - Some questions about FileConnection/JSR 75](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=26417)
[Use System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard") to check if SDCard available](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=152357)
[How to save & delete a Bitmap image in Blackberry Storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351273/how-to-save-delete-a-bitmap-image-in-blackberry-storm)