# BlackBerry - How to resize and store image?

Tags: image, graphics, blackberry, file-io, resize

I need to scale image to small and store that image in to blackberry device (as a small image)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scaling an image is straightforward enough if the image is packaged, or even sourced over the network or filesystem.

```
public EncodedImage scaleImage(EncodedImage source, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight) {  
  int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getWidth());  
  int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredWidth);  
  int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);  
  int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getHeight());  
  int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredHeight);  
  int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);  
  return source.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);  
}
```

this returns a copy of the image, scaled according to the width and height you require it to be.

Comment: saving it on device, you have options: filesystem or persistentStorage?

Comment: Trying all kinds of different things:  many from this website - nothing worked until I tried your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See
[BlackBerry - How to resize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769755/blackberry-how-to-resize-image)
[How to save & delete a Bitmap image in Blackberry Storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351273/how-to-save-delete-a-bitmap-image-in-blackberry-storm)